# Pod install, The dependency `*****` is not used in any concrete target

Tags: ios, cocoapods, cocoapods-1.1.1

When performing `pod install` on a project I get the following output:

```
Analyzing dependencies
[!] The dependency `MMDrawerController (~> 0.5.7)` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `ViewUtils` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `CPAnimationSequence` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `iCarousel` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `BlocksKit (~> 2.2.5)` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `AFNetworking` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `MBProgressHUD (~> 0.8)` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `NSString-UrlEncode` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `INTULocationManager` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `SDWebImage (= 3.7.2)` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `Adjust (from `https://github.com/adjust/ios_sdk.git`, tag `v3.4.0`)` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `TARTT (from `https://github.com/takondi/tartt-sdk-ios.git`)` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `SIAlertView (~> 1.3)` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `GoogleAppIndexing` is not used in any concrete target.
The dependency `Gimbal` is not used in any concrete target.
```

How do I resolve this issue so that the install works correctly?

There's more than 20 targets and a post_install pattern could this contribute to the problem?

My CocoaPod version is 1.1.1.

Here is the Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '7.0'

pod 'MMDrawerController', '~> 0.5.7'
pod 'ViewUtils'
pod 'CPAnimationSequence'
pod 'iCarousel'
pod 'BlocksKit', '~> 2.2.5'
pod 'AFNetworking'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.8'
pod 'NSString-UrlEncode'
pod 'INTULocationManager'
pod 'SDWebImage', '3.7.2'
pod 'Adjust', :git => 'https://github.com/adjust/ios_sdk.git', :tag => 'v3.4.0'
pod 'TARTT', :git => 'https://github.com/takondi/tartt-sdk-ios.git'
pod 'SIAlertView', '~> 1.3'
pod 'GoogleAppIndexing'
pod 'Gimbal'

post_install do |installer_representation|
    installer_representation.project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'NO'
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: @did you `pod init` in your project folder? What do you mean that your project has more than 20 targets?

Comment: @mat because when it has only a target, they will use target 'MyApp'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 1.0' ... , but when the project has more target, they use Hooks is practicality i think

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Your `Podfile` should contains information in which target you want to install the cocoapods. The post installer in your Podfile sets only `ACTIVE_ARCH` flag to `NO` in each target.

If you have more than 20 targets in your app(and some mess in current Podfile), maybe try to remove `Podfile` and `Podfile.lock` and then do `pod init`. It will make CococaPods gem create a valid `Podfile` for your app. Then paste the CocoaPods that your app using and paste the post installer instruction to the new Podfile and try to reinstall cocoapods using `pod install`.

Remember to place pod instructions between correct target.

Look at the [CocoaPods site](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html) about Podfile.

So your Podfile should look like:

```
target 'YourTargetName' do

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '7.0'

pod 'MMDrawerController', '~> 0.5.7'
pod 'ViewUtils'
pod 'CPAnimationSequence'
pod 'iCarousel'
pod 'BlocksKit', '~> 2.2.5'
pod 'AFNetworking'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.8'
pod 'NSString-UrlEncode'
pod 'INTULocationManager'
pod 'SDWebImage', '3.7.2'
pod 'Adjust', :git => 'https://github.com/adjust/ios_sdk.git', :tag => 'v3.4.0'
pod 'TARTT', :git => 'https://github.com/takondi/tartt-sdk-ios.git'
pod 'SIAlertView', '~> 1.3'
pod 'GoogleAppIndexing'
pod 'Gimbal'

post_install do |installer_representation|
  installer_representation.project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
end
```

Comment: thanks @k8mil, but i get the project from another, the podfile looks like this, they doesn't add any target in the head of the file but works fine. maybe they use a old pod version?

Comment: Maybe they use old version of cocoapods, and on your computer CocoaPods version is latest. If exist check maybe in `gemfile.lock` the version of CocoaPods that should be used in your project.

Comment: i will try, thinks

Comment: Yes, it's correct. Must to remove all podfile.lock and .xcworkspace and then init pod again.

Comment: I want to highlight that `source` is going to clone that repo which is ~ 1GB in size. If you have `Cocoapods` already installed, you may want to avoid this. Also, you'll need to provide the path to the workspace `workspace '../path/to/your/project.xcworkspace/'` and the path to the project `project '../path/to/your/project.xcodeproj/'`

Comment: Correction. It is actually ~3GB.

Answer (score 35):

Simply add your pod file in below block

```
target 'YourApp' do
  pod '*******', '~> 1.0'
end
```

Comment: YourApp = Bundle Name

Comment: Thanks! This is a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little weird, but the Gimbal SDK contains iCarousel so it might have problems with your podfile.

[Source](https://manager.gimbal.com/notices/notice_ios_v2.txt)