# How to add Firebase to Today Extension iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods, today-extension

I need to be able to use Firebase in my Today View Extension, however I cannot seem to import the Firebase module. I think it's because I need a new target in my cocoa pods file, but I'm not sure on how to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to treat the today extension as its own separate app(somewhat)

in your firebase project dashboard, you need to hit the "Add another app" button.

[image]

select iOS and then enter the **BUNDLE ID** of your **TODAY EXTENSION**

[image]

Complete the wizard and download the generated **GoogleService-Info.plist** file

Add the plist file to your **Today Extension's root folder**

go to your xcode project, and manually add **FirebaseCore.framework and FirebaseDatabase.framework** to your Today Extension

[image: step 1 : get your bundle id step 2 : add frameworks]

finally inside your today today viewcontroller call FirebaseApp.configure()

```
import FirebaseDatabase 
import FirebaseCore


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    FirebaseApp.configure() 
}
```

Comment: Seen as it is two different 'apps' does that mean that I cannot use data from where all my data is? Eg can my extension 'app' access the data in my current database?

Comment: ok just to clear a few things up...
1) At your Firebase Console (https://console.firebase.google.com/)
2) Choose your EXISTING Firebase Project.
3) You are then adding an "app" to your EXISTING Firebase Project.
4) Your Firebase Database(for your EXISTING Firebase Project) will be accessible to all "apps" within that EXISTING Firebase Project.
5) Please select my answer if this solution has worked for you :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but can we add the Firebase not manually but via pod to the app and today extension? I've tried to do that but my app cruch! please check my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46826315/4498576  I will be sooo thankful for any help :(

Comment: it seems it's required to check that [FIRApp defaultApp] is not null already to not to have a crash that the app is already configured

Comment: But what if the user needs to be logged in?

Comment: you can share data (im guessing a session token or something) between the widget and the main app by enabling "app groups" in both of their respective target capabilities.

Comment: Your solution looks correct but there is an issue that I'm facing right now. I perfectly implement Firebase and configure FirebaseApp but I couldn't observe data. Do you have any idea why? @CharlieNorris

Answer (score 11):

Or without adding an extra app at the Firebase console, just re-use your main project's `GoogleService-Info.plist` with a minor modification (see below). The Firebase app singleton would have to be configured either way in both apps on startup.

To synchronize an extension and the containing app see [App Extension Programming Guide: Handling Common Scenarios](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW6) or [this reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/6t8pzu/sharing_firebase_authentication_with_ios/dlp6uvq). [**This Stackoverflow thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46442299/user-not-signed-into-firebase-in-share-app-extension) specifically describes this scenario.

**Steps**:

1. Copy the containing app's `GoogleService-Info.plist` into your extension in Xcode
2. Drag the copied `GoogleService-Info.plist` into Xcode into your share extension and
3. Change the BUNDLE_ID to the name of your share extension's target
4. Add new target to your `Podfile`
5. Install dependencies (`pod install`)
6. Configure the Firebase application object in your extension

---

#### Step 1. Copy the containing app's `GoogleService-Info.plist` into your extension in Xcode

#### Step 2. Drag the copied `GoogleService-Info.plist` into Xcode into your share extension and

#### Step 3. Change the BUNDLE_ID to the name of your share extension's target

For us the main (i.e., containing app) is `Access News` and the share extension is `Access-News-Uploader`.

[image]

[image]

#### Step 4. Add new target to your `Podfile`

```
# ...

target 'name-of-your-extension' do

  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  # etc.
end
```

[Entire `Podfile` of our project](https://github.com/society-for-the-blind/Access-News-Reader_iOS/blob/c137fd77e6889ebfb89740e85a24bf3109b5f977/Podfile).

#### Step 5. Install dependencies (`pod install`)

#### Step 6. Configure the Firebase application object in your extension

```
/* 1. Import Firebase */
/**********************/
import Firebase
/**********************/

class WhereverInYourExtension: WhateverController {

    // ...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        /* 2. Configure Firebase */
        /*************************/
        if FirebaseApp.app() == nil {
            FirebaseApp.configure()
        }
        /*************************/

        // ...
    }
```

---

#### Pod issue fixes

> **1)** Still unable to import Firebase!

Make sure that pods are installed for all targets in your project. To achieve this use [`inherit!`](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#inherit_bang) or [`abstract_target`](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#abstract_target) in your Podfile.

The simplest example using `abstract_target` from [the official documentation](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#inherit_bang):

```
abstract_target 'Networking' do
  pod 'AlamoFire'

  target 'Networking App 1'
  target 'Networking App 2'
end
```

For `inherit!`, see [this SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42114122/using-cocoapods-in-an-app-extension-using-a-framework).

> **2)** How do I achieve this on my existing app without messing things up?

1. Remove `Podfile`, `Podfile.lock` and `YourProject.xcworkspace`
2. Issue `pod init` and it will list your existing targets one by one.
3. Edit the `Podfile` by either grouping under `abstract_target` or using `inherit!`
4. Issue `pod install`

A new `YourProject.xcworkspace` file will be generated, and if you open the your project using this, under `General` > `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` it will show that Firebase is added and can be imported from project files.

(See [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40234810/pod-install-the-dependency-is-not-used-in-any-concrete-target) for a concrete example where this clean-up method needed to be used.)

> **3)** `firebase 'sharedApplication' is unavailable: not available on iOS (App Extension) - Use view controller based solutions where appropriate instead.`

This is what worked for me:

1. wiped everything clean by cloning our project repo fresh from Github,
2. deleted

   - ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
   - ./Pods/
   - Podfile
   - Podfile.lock
3. Issue `pod init` on the console
4. Recreate `Podfile` (basically copy-paste)
5. Issue `pod update` on the console

(Probably won't work next time.)

Comment: i am already done to istall firebase but issue is Firebase Database is not updating in i am already done to istall firebase but issue is Firebase Database is not updating in UNNotificationServiceExtension what should i do? what should i do?

Comment: he project's Bundle ID is inconsistent with either the Bundle ID in 'GoogleService-Info.plist', or the Bundle ID in the options if you are using a customized options. To ensure that everything can be configured correctly, you may need to make the Bundle IDs consistent. To continue with this plist file, you may change your app's bundle identifier to bundle id. Or you can download a new configuration file that matches your bundle identifier from https://console.firebase.google.com/ and replace the current one.

Comment: Thank you! I haven't been doing iOS dev lately, and don't even have the hardware anymore to test it, so please feel free to update the answer if there are any inaccuracies.

Comment: one other issue i am fail to get the permisson of firebase auth this is an issue

Answer (score -4):

To my knowledge widgets are not allowed to use certain api's such as firebase. Widgets are supposed to show data provided by the main application via **UserDefaults** e.g.

TodayViewExtensions (or widgets) may only be very light codewise.

Comment: I don't believe so, all I want to do is to show the most recent post that someone made to the thread. Iv seen lots of other apps do this, for example Flipboard