# Enable Firebase Authentication in Share Extension

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an app that also has a Share Extension from which I would like to access Firebase but I struggle with permissions...

I tried `useUserAccessGroup` like this:

**Main App:**

```
do {
    try Auth.auth().useUserAccessGroup(UserDefaults.Keys.groupKey)
} catch let error as NSError {
  print("Error changing user access group: %@", error)
}
let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
// set user status to logged-in
if let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: UserDefaults.Keys.groupKey) {
    defaults.setIsLoggedIn(value: true)
    defaults.setUid(uid: uid)
    defaults.synchronize()
}
```

**Share Extension**:

```
do {
    try Auth.auth().useUserAccessGroup(UserDefaults.Keys.groupKey)
} catch let error as NSError {
  print("Error changing user access group: %@", error)
}
let imageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("images").child(imageName)
imageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { (metaData, err) in
...
```

I guess I am doing something wrong but I don't know what the problem is from reading the Firebase Documentation, so if anyone know the easiest way to get this done I am very grateful!

Comment: Where does this code live in the app and the extension?

Comment: @KaylaGalway does that matter ? in the main app just before the user logs in and in the extension right before I retrieve some data

Comment: It only matters because some extensions timeout, and I'm not sure if the Share Extension is one of them or not.  But I think I initially misread this - you are not able to access Firebase on the main app or the extension?

Comment: @KaylaGalway Extension. But I am able to access it, just not able to authenticate

Comment: where is your Auth (class / struct) located?

Comment: @IlyaMuradymov not quite sure what youre asking. `Auth` is from Firebase

Comment: Oh, ok, I've not used Firebase for couple of years. So, you have installed it via Cocoapods? You sure your extension have correct access to this pod?

Comment: @IlyaMuradymov yes and yes

Comment: which means, your extension target is in Podfile?

Comment: @IlyaMuradymov yes it is

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218579/discussion-between-chris-and-ilya-muradymov).

Answer (score 2):

S0.
The thoughts is Firebase using for auth mechanism some parts of system that is not accessible from extension. Have you set up Keychain Sharing?

Please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46442299/user-not-signed-into-firebase-in-share-app-extension), [this](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/2179)

Pls, keep me updated if succeed or not. Thnx.

Comment: could you have a look at my latest question ?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64668523/authenticate-user-in-share-extension-with-firebase?noredirect=1#comment114375822_64668523