# Swift Signing User in with Access Group not working

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Inside my app I would like to sign in the user using `Auth.auth().useUserAccessGroup`.

This is my code for signing in with email (user can also sign in with Facebook, Google & Apple):

**signUp-Function:**

```
static func signUpWithEmail(email: String, password: String, username: String, finished: @escaping (_ done: Bool) -> Void){
    
    do {
        try Auth.auth().useUserAccessGroup("SN26HDFT24.com.wishlists-app.group")
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error changing user access group: %@", error)
    }
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in
        
        if let error = error {
            Utilities.showErrorPopUp(labelContent: "Fehler", description: error.localizedDescription)
            finished(false)
        }
        
        if let userId = result?.user.uid { 

             // successfully signed in

        } else {
            print("user couldn't sign in")
            finished(false)
        }
    }
}
```

**Keychain Sharing:**

[image: asdf]

**Problem:**

When calling this function `if let error = error` this fails:

> The @c NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey field in the @c NSError.userInfo dictionary will contain more information about the error encountered" UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_KEYCHAIN_ERROR, NSLocalizedFailureReason=SecItemCopyMatching (-34018), NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred when accessing the keychain. The @c NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey field in the @c NSError.userInfo dictionary will contain more information about the error encountered}

so the first time I am calling it, `try Auth.auth().useUserAccessGroup("SN26HDFT24.com.wishlists-app.group")` actually succeeds, at least it is not throwing anything.

But when calling it again it the `do try block` fails. With the same error-message as above.

**Entitlements:**

[image]

**Capabilities:**

[image]

I am stuck. Couldn't find anything on this anywhere...

***This is for my Share Extensnion:***

[image]

Comment: It should be sufficient to call this only once after initializing the firebase app (`FirebaseApp.configure()`).

Comment: @cybergen tried that as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how this could happen, but the string for the access group is wrong in your entitlements.

It should be `$(AppIdentifierPrefix)com.wishlists-app.group` instead of `$(AppIdentifierPrefix)SN26HDFT24.com.wishlists-app.group`.

Your extension must have the same app group and keychain group activated. I can't see anything of your app extension. Then you must also call `useUserAccessGroup("SN26HDFT24.com.wishlists-app.group")` in your extension.

Comment: are you sure? I thought I have to use the team id at the front for keychain access

Comment: Pretty sure. I looked into our (wishlist ;-)) project, where it works. Nevertheless, we have issues with our share extension. When logging out and in again in our main app, the extension stays logged out until the app calling the share extension (e.g. Amazon or Safari) is killed and restarted.

Comment: $(AppIdentifierPrefix) should be your team id.

Comment: oh its you haha :D ok I will give it a try! why don't I see any sign ins in my database from your end ?

Comment: It's me who? I'm probably not a user of your particular app.

Comment: oh ok haha nvm then :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224633/discussion-between-chris-and-cybergen).

Comment: @Chris did you look into the chat? Did it help?

Comment: so the 2nd problem was that I was running an older Firebase version where calling useUserAccessGroup right after Firebase.configure() was a known bug but that got fixed. Everything is working now! You can not understand how much you helped me! was struggling with this for half a year now. Thanks!