# Using Firebase in the App and Today Extension doesn't work

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, today-extension

I'm using Firebase in My App, I used it via **pod** and everything was work correctly,

Then we Add Today Extensions (2 extensions) to our app, and also we need to use Firebase in it, so I added it to **podfile** like this:

```
use_frameworks!
 project ‘projectName.xcodeproj'

  target ‘appName’ do

        pod 'Firebase/Core'

  post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
    end
end
end

end

target ‘todayExtension1_Name’ do

pod 'Firebase/Core'

end 

 target ‘todayExtension2_Name’ do

pod 'Firebase/Core'

end
```

and I create two apps for the todayExtensions, and implement the .plist files correctly and the app build successfully.

but when I try to **run** the app, I got this runtime exception:

> dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMLogLevelFilter
>     Referenced from: /Users/rawanal-omari/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/33A7DC45-EFD9-4245-8989-7C6B4194481F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/84C060C2-A4AE-4AF3-8804-ADA8CFBCABB3/appName.app/appName
>     Expected in: /Users/rawanal-omari/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/33A7DC45-EFD9-4245-8989-7C6B4194481F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/84C060C2-A4AE-4AF3-8804-ADA8CFBCABB3/appName.app/Frameworks/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac
>    in /Users/rawanal-omari/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/33A7DC45-EFD9-4245-8989-7C6B4194481F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/84C060C2-A4AE-4AF3-8804-ADA8CFBCABB3/appName.app/appName

Did anyone face problem like this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if targeting the extensions via pods is enough,
But the following steps are needed

Step 1. Go to your firebase console.

Step 2. Click on the project you are working on.

[image: Firebase dashboard]

Step 3. Within the project, click on "Add another app"
[image: add another app]

Step 4. Select iOS and then enter the BUNDLE ID of your TODAY EXTENSION
[image: bundle id]

Step 5. Complete the wizard and download the generated GoogleService-Info.plist file. Add the plist file to your Today Extension's root folder

From here you can try adding firebase via pods to your extensions.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but actually I did all these steps before I add the firebase to pod :(

Comment: ah ok....btw is there any reason why you wouldnt want to add it manually?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? I have the same problem with a Messages extension and I am stuck.

Comment: I don't think that pod file installation and firebase GoogleService-Info.plist steps are dependent on each other

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case I've added the 'Firebase/Performance' pod to the app target, but not to the extension target. After adding it to the extension too, I was able to run the app again.

Conclusion: add the Firebase pods you're using in your app target, to the extension target too