# Build error. Installing Firebase in Xcode iOS app with multiple targets and NotificationServiceExtensions

Tags: ios, firebase

I'm trying to integrate Firebase (for Dynamic Links) in my current Xcode iOS project but I have problems with errors in the build  (Following this documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive).

My Podfile looks like this:

```
# Uncomment the next line...
# platform :ios, '9.0'


target 'AppName1' do
    # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks

    use_frameworks!


    # Pods for AppName1
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
    pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
end


target 'NotificationServiceExtension' do
    # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks

    use_frameworks!


    # Pods for NotificationServiceExtension
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
    pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'end


(... With more targets ...)
```

TEST1. When I try to complile the App target, this is the errors I am getting:

[Error1 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqCnO.png)

```
'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found
Firebase.h
While building module 'Firebase' imported from */AppDelegate.h:1.1:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:

Could not build module 'Firebase'
AppDelegate.h
In the file included from */ViewControllerLogin.m:9:
In the file included from */ViewControllerLogin.h:10:
```

TEST2. If I remove the "pod 'Firebase/ ..." lines from the NotificationServiceExtensions I get these errors:

[Error2 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wbxP.png)

```
'sharedApplication' is unavailable: not available on iOS (App Extension) - Use view controller based solutions where appropriate instead.

'openURL:' is unavailable: not available on iOS (App Extension)
```

TEST1. If I comment the "use_frameworks!" with #, I get the first errors again.

TEST2. If I comment everything inside the targets NotificationServiceExtensions I get:

```
Library not found for -lFirebaseCore
```

For every test I'm doing "pod deintegrate" and "pod install" again, open the PROJECT-NAME.xcworkspace, clean and build.

I don't know what else to try or what I'm doing wrong... (the integration with android was super easy...)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was related to xcode not building the pods target with the app target.

The correct configuration in the pods file was including the "pod 'Firebase/Analytics' pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'" only in the target apps and not in the target Extensions (TEST2 in the question).

After executing "pod update" or "pod install" and opening the correct "your-project.xcworkspace" the answer was to go to Build Settings of the Pods parent Target and set the setting "**Build Active Architecture Only**" to "**No**" (Every time a pod is updated, this setting returns to "Yes" in Debug mode). With this, the Pod Target gets build alongside the App Target.

Comment: But this time it raised many "Undefined symbols" error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
target 'AppName1' do
# Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks

use_frameworks!


# Pods for AppName1
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'

target 'NotificationServiceExtension' do
# Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks

use_frameworks!


# Pods for NotificationServiceExtension
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'

  end
end

post_install do |installer|
   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    puts target.name
 end
end
```

CocoaPods [docs](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html)

Comment: It didn't work, I get the Error2 from the question. I suspect it has something to do with the Extensions not working well with Firebase (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50592585/can-firebaseauth-5-0-x-be-used-in-an-ios-app-extension/50607314#50607314) but I don't know what to do.

Comment: I get the Error2 setting only the targets to NO (require only App-Extension-Safe Api to NO). And if a set everything on the Pod to NO I get a new error: "ld: framework not found Pods_AppName1 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)". I also tried multiple variations of this with no luck...

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Dynamic Links is not currently supported in extensions.

File an issue at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk to request for consideration.